# Will Apache Sqoop support data transfer from HIVE to Cassandra.

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, sqoop

None of these (Hive/ Cassandra) are relational.
Hive being JDBC supported, I think is compatible with Hive.

Comment: not possible with cassandra to hdfs/HIVE if you just use `sqoop` - https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct Sqoop works with JDBC. For example, with [Progress JDBC driver](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/apache-cassandra), you can export from HDFS to Cassandra as follows from Sqoop:

```
sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:datadirect:cassandra://MyServer:9042;KeyspaceName=MyKS' --driver com.ddtek.jdbc.cassandra.CassandraDriver --table 'blah_1024MB' --export-dir /user/hdfs/blah_1024MB/ --input-lines-terminated-by "n" --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --batch -m 10
```

Comment: Would this be possible the other way around (import into HDFS from Cassandra)? If so, how would that work?

Comment: @usr Were you able to figure this out? Do you mind sharing the answer?